# Prevent tab navigation from leaving element

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to enable tab navigation among the interactive elements of a group which has focus.
For example, if the focus was given to `modal`, navigating using Tab key should stay in that element, and not share the tab indexing with the outer elements.

Is there any way to achieve this? (I'm using Angular 14, so perhaps there's something already available)

```
<div id="main-page">
  <a tabindex="1"></a>
  <a tabindex="2"></a>
  <a tabindex="3"></a>
</div>

<div id="modal">
  <a tabindex="1"></a>
  <a tabindex="2"></a>
  <a tabindex="3"></a>
</div>
```

Something similar to what WPF's `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"` do.

---

Something weird, is that for a modal, that appears on top of other elements, even if the tabindex is using a high number (away from the ones used by the elements in the main page), the focus will go away from the modal.

Comment: It's called **focus trap**

Answer (score 1):

The tabindex value of greater than 0 (positive value) won't make the focus only travels among them. It only tells the browser about the priority. Also, using tabindex with a positive value needs to be avoided. [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex):

> Warning: Avoid using tabindex values greater than 0. Doing so makes it difficult for people who rely on assistive technology to navigate and operate page content. Instead, write the document with the elements in a logical sequence.

One of the methods to achieve your goal is by using **focus trap**. there is [an example from W3C](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/dialog-modal/dialog.html). Also, I think there are some js libraries that are available in npm.

The other way is by using the HTML property [inert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/inert), but this feature is pretty new and only the latest version of major browsers supports it at this time.

I think the best option, for now, is to use the focus trap.